# WPF styles from another assembly are not being applied

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

i'm loading styles from another assembly in my project, for example:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CommonStyles;component/CommonStylesDictionary.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

for some unknown reason, in some computers my app looks as designed and in some computers some(not all!) of the styles are not applied correctly(like scrollviewer for example).

any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have downloaded correct SDK's in the machines and the refrences are correctly loaded.

Comment: how can i know which SDK i'm missing? 
@Alias Varghese